# Django - how to dedicate certein app to database

Tags: mysql, database, django, django-models, sqlite

I've read Django docs, but I am afraid I don't really understand what is written, and what they are trying to explain. I want to know how I can dedicate one app to one database, 2nd app to 2nd databse, etc.
I get the part where I am inserting new databases in settings.py, but the tricky part for me is when I have to connect apps and databases>

Example:

I want to add some text to 1st db from 1st app, then I want to add another text to 2nd db, and all that in real time, on actual server.

Any help?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use separate databases for each app? Databases are pretty powerful and can handle lots of tables. In general, you'll probably find it easier to keep it all in one database unless you have a specific reason for doing otherwise.

Comment: Well, I find it more practical then storing everything in one db.That's the reason.

Comment: And there will be a time when I am going to need 2nd db, for whatever reason.

Comment: I'm not here to tell you that you're *wrong*, but I think you should consider this carefully. There are a whole host of difficulties in stringing up multiple databases, and many, many Django users rely on one database. Again, I don't want to say there's no reason not to, but it should be well-considered and specific.

Comment: Hmm. Ok then. I will have this in mind. But I wanted to know this method, I can never know when I am going to need it.

Comment: There are no problems with multiple database if you keep them isolated from each other, I mean, no database system will be able to manage "SAFELY" cross foreignkeys between different databases. I have done it once because I didn't have a choice and Django did a really good job with cross foreignkeys, but just few times I had to tell Django what database should follow going through some foreign key or related_name. If there is not a good reason, you should put everything in the same database, if you don't want to see yourself hunting ghosts. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with routes, here you have Multi database in Django:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/multi-db/

and here the core about how to do it:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing

Basically define a Router for each APP you can get the name of the model you are working with.

Comment: That's exactly what I read where I had troubles understanding the same.